# Prepend all array elements before a certain index in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to create a function that will format the paths for my breadcrumbs. I have a basic idea of what I want to do but not sure how to implement it. I want to prepend everything in the array before a certain index inside of a loop and do it for every element of that array. I currently have the following code but the issue is that `$breadcrumbs[0]` is being defined by me, I need it to be automatically defined inside of PHP.

```
public static function formatBreadcrumbs ($path) {
    // Explode path into an array
    $breadcrumbs = explode('/', $path);

    $counter = 0;

    foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) {
        if ($breadcrumb !== $breadcrumbs[0]) {
            $formattedBreadcrumbs[] = $breadcrumbs[0] . '/' . $breadcrumb;
        }
    }

    var_dump($formattedBreadcrumbs);
}
```

For example if I input an array such as:

```
$path = array(
    'documents',
    'text',
    'work'
);
```

I would want my function to output:

```
$formattedPath = array(
    'documents',
    'documents/text',
    'documents/text/work'
);
```

In theory, this seems pretty simple but the logic behind it is boggling my mind a bit. Any help would be great, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path = array(
    'documents',
    'text',
    'work'
);

$cur_path = '';
$new_array = array();
$count = 0;
foreach($path as $path_item)
{
    if($count == 0)
    {
        $cur_path = $path_item;
    }
    else
    {
        $cur_path .= '/' . $path_item;
    }

    $new_array[] = $cur_path;
    $count++;
}
```

Tested. $new_array should equal:

```
Array ( [0] => documents [1] => documents/text [2] => documents/text/work )
```

Comment: Working like a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, but I personally prefer Martavis Griffin's answer. It's exactly the same logic, but cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can work something like this...

```
$breadcrumbs = array(
'documents',
'text',
'work'
);

$slash = '';
$string = '';
$breadcrumbArray = Array();

foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) {
    $string = $breadcrumbArray[] = $string.$slash.$breadcrumb;
    $slash = "/";
}
```

Comment: Clever. I used a $count but this is much nicer looking.

Answer (score 1):

This function here will do this for you:

```
function formatBreadcrumbs ($path) {
    $exitArray = array();
    $temp = '';

    for ($i = 0;$i < sizeof($path);$i++)
    {
        if ($temp == '')
            $temp = $path[$i];
        else
            $temp = $temp . '/' . $path[$i];

        $exitArray[$i] = $temp;
    }

    return $exitArray;
}
```

This takes input like:

```
$path = array(
    'documents',
    'text',
    'work'
);
```

And return:

```
array(
    'documents',
    'documents/text',
    'documents/text/work'
);
```

So you can use it like this:

```
$formattedPath = formatBreadcrumbs($path);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop that calls `implode()` on successive subsets of the original array, using `array_slice`.

```
$formattedBreadcrumbs = array();
$len = count($breadcrumbs);
for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i++) {
    $formattedBreadcrumbs[] = implode('/', array_slice($breadcrumbs, 0, $i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$prefix=null;
$formattedPath =  = array_map(function($a)use(&$prefix){
  return $prefix = ($prefix ? "$prefix/$a" : $a);
},$path);
//4+ answer, so no comment here :)
```